# How to install docker-ce in kali-linux?

Tags: linux, kali-linux, docker, upgrade

I tried installing Docker recently, but ever since its installation I cannot update kali-linux anymore.

this is the output after i input "sudo apt update"

```
Hit:1 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:2 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian kali-rolling InRelease
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian kali-rolling Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 13.227.73.95 443]
Hit:3 http://mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu/kali kali-rolling InRelease
Reading package lists... Done              
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/debian kali-rolling Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Maybe you are using the using the wrong distro : https://www.kali.org/docs/introduction/should-i-use-kali-linux/#is-kali-linux-right-for-you

Comment: It seems that you are trying to use Kali (from `https://www.kali.org`: __Kali Linux__ is an open-source, Debian-based Linux distribution geared towards various information security tasks, such as Penetration Testing, Security Research, Computer Forensics and Reverse Engineering. ) as a general purpose Linux. This is unwise.

Answer (score 8):

Use `debian` codename in your sources:

Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable
```

or use the following command:

```
printf "%s\n" "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian buster stable" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list
```

Add the gpg key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

install `docker-ce`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

[Install Docker Engine on Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)

**Update**

I have updated the [Kali Linux documentation](https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/installing-docker-on-kali/), now you can safely add the Debian docker-ce Repository as described in this answer. And here is how to install it:

> Installing docker-ce on Kali Linux

> docker-ce can be installed from Docker repository using Debian buster codename.

> Add Docker repository to your sources.list

```
printf "%s\n" "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable" |\
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list
```

> Import the gpg key:

```
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

> Fingerprint checking:

```
sudo apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88
```

> Install the latest version of docker-ce:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

References

> [Install Docker Engine on Debian](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/debian/)

Comment: As of April 2023, Debian’s current stable version is `bullseye`, not `buster` - See: https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/installing-docker-on-kali/

Answer (score 1):

[The official Kali Linux Docker guide](https://www.kali.org/docs/containers/installing-docker-on-kali/) states that:

> One thing to bear in mind, Kali Linux is based on Debian, so we need
> to use Debian’s current stable version (even though Kali Linux is a
> rolling distribution). At the time of writing (**Dec. 2021**), its
> “**bullseye**”

As you can see the Debian's stable version (as of April 2023) is `bullseye`, not `kali-rolling`. When you visit this URL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/dists/, you won't even see any `kali-rolling` in there.

For that reason, if you want to remove the error, you should open these files:

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`
- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list`

and replace all occurrences of `kali-rolling` with `bullseye`.

For example, in my case, I have this:

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list`:

```
deb [arch=amd64 signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] 
https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
```

- `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker-ce.list`:

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye stable
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to use the official (and usually preferred) install script without editing system files is to inject an option for `kali-linux` (or any other distribution) and link it to the preferred docker version on the fly:

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com |\
sed 's/case "$dist_version" in/case "$dist_version" in kali-rolling)dist_version="bullseye";;/g' |\
sudo sh
```

This will replace the line `case "$dist_version" in` with the following code (indentation added for optics) to the install script's function that determins the Debian version, adding an option for Kali:

```
case "$dist_version" in
  kali-rolling)
    dist_version="bullseye"
;;
```

Adjust `dist_version="bullseye"` accordingly to specify a different distro to mimic.

Follow up with the usual commands as needed to enable the Kali user to run docker without `sudo` and activate the docker service:

```
usermod -aG docker kali
systemctl enable docker
```